# In python-oauth2 how do you retain oauth_token_secret parameter?

Tags: python-2.7, oauth-2.0, twitter-oauth

I'm trying to follow this Oauth2 guide for Sign in With Twitter https://github.com/simplegeo/python-oauth2 - Everything is going great until between steps 2 and 3.  I handle the the callback fine, but how do I pass along the oauth_token_secret?  My confusion is that it seems like it's lost after the redirect back to my handler.

From what I can tell the parameters I get back are oauth_token and oauth_verifier, and yet I need the oauth_token_secret to receive the access token in these steps.

```
token = oauth.Token(request_token['oauth_token'],
request_token['oauth_token_secret'])
token.set_verifier(oauth_verifier)
client = oauth.Client(consumer, token)

resp, content = client.request(access_token_url, "POST")
access_token = dict(urlparse.parse_qsl(content))
```

Am I supposed to store it in a cookie to retrieve later?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this by storing the oauth_token and oauth_token_secret in a session during step one.  These values are stored from the created request token `request_token['oauth_token']`